# Firebase for (non Android) Java application

Tags: java, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am building Java application with Firebase:

```
void InsertData(){
    User user = new User("ABC", "Mumbai");

    ref.push().setValue(user, new DatabaseReference.CompletionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(DatabaseError error, DatabaseReference ref) {
            System.out.println("Value was set. Error = "+error);
            System.out.println("Value was set. Done = "+ref);
        }
    });
}
```

This is my code the data is not inserted in realtime database `onComeplete` code is not executing.

Comment: Do you have an error?

Comment: no error, but no output too